# Runtime method binding

Tags: c#, polymorphism, dispatch

Is there a formal name for what I've outlined below. The example is in c#, but the premise would apply to other langs. I'm almost certain I've done something like this years ago in some other lang, but what one, or the name of the concept escapes me. dynamic dispatch(of sorts)??

The key point I'm trying to convey, is that at runtime, the method to execute is determined, and called. The methods would have almost same signature, only differing by the type of the argument, and that the arguments are all in the same inheritance tree too. I know there are some details I've left out, but I want to keep the example simple.

```
string result;
User u;
User user = new User();
Manager manager = new Manager();

u = user;
result = _Print(u);
Console.WriteLine(result); // user...

u = manager;
result = _Print(u);
Console.WriteLine(result); // manager...
```

---

```
// interested in part
private static string _Print(User u)
{
    return (u is Manager) ? Print((Manager)u) : Print(u);
}
```

---

```
// plumbing
private static string Print(User u)
{
    return "User...";
}
private static string Print(Manager m)
{
    return "Manager...";
}

class User { ... }
class Manager : User { ... }
```

Comment: Isn't this an anti-pattern? Shouldn't the user be responsible for providing the print data?

Comment: its only like that for the case of the example. the payload of each method is only there to provide context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). I learn it as dynamic binding, because it is a function binding feature provided by many OO languages such as Java, that implements it by default, and C++, in which it requires in the explicit keyword "virtual" for it to work in a [dynamic fashion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch#C.2B.2B_Implementation) - by default c++ is static binding. However, modern in OO the dynamic binding is easily achieved by [Polimorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#C.23) and [Overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading). So you can have something like this:

```
User u = new User(); 
Console.WriteLine(u.print()); // user...

u = new Manager();
Console.WriteLine(u.print()); // manager...


class User { ... 
    public string print(User u)
    {
        return "User...";
    }
... }
class Manager : User { ... 
    public string print(Manager m)
    {
        return "Manager...";
    }

... }
```

But you need to adapt to your language. I do not know much about C# and there are so many idiosyncrasies. I found this post with some examples for you - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dynamicbindingincsharp.aspx

Comment: yea, i know polymorphism, but my example is different, as its where the language will choose the method based on the type of the argument, at runtime. 

looking at that article on wikipedia on dynamic dispatch, (the C++) section, its talking about overriding, which is not what is above. it also has the following to say in the dynamic dispatch article "Expressed in pseudocode, the code manager.handle(y) could call different implementations depending on the type of object y. This is known as multiple dispatch". is this correct?

Comment: yes, you can do a multiple dispatch, but it is something different than overriding. your code looks like overriding. what you say reminds me of the strategy pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern - you can switch the algorithm to handle something on runtime (it can be based on a type of the parameter, a flag, or something else).